# Battery status on Windows Phone app

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I receive data about the battery status for windows phone ? I checked on microsoft's site but i couldn't find anything except the charging mode :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to determine the battery state of the device. You may want to consider why this is. I think it is because an application you may deploy to the device does not need to know this information as it should be left up to the user to determine whether they need to charge their device, given adequate notification of any low battery state. This would then make your application alot simplier as you don't need to concern yourself with the device's battery level. Something else to consider is what would you do with the information regarding the battery state, display the battery level, I don't think so seeing as the status bar already contains a battery indicator. Knowing the battery level, would you then display a notification regarding a low battery state, again this is already covered.

Comment: it does not makes sense !!
i would like to make a tile tha show the battery state with bigger icons :S

as an example : in android there a billion of applications like this !!

why microsoft is so stupid  ??? it does not makes sense ... :O

thank you any way :)